Back HDRi Projection onto mesh
I want to back an HDRi projection onto the mesh I have set up.
My HDRi is a tone-mapped version of the original HDRi. Now I need to back this projection onto the mesh it is projected on. (sometimes a square, rectangular, cylinder ect...), so I can export them as FBX and import them into other applications.
I can not find a way to bake my 360 tone-mapped HDRi.
Any ideas?
Thank you
